# Is it possible that dark matter is civilization?

Tags: history

If the zoo theory is correct. Is it possible that dark matter then is civilization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the data the dark matter behaves as if it had not only almost no non-gravitational interaction with the ordinary matter but also almost no self-interaction. So the Dark matter forms just clouds of boring ghostly stuff. The civilizations as we know them are formed by a matter that interacts in a rather sophisticated fashion.